# LEFT JOIN query returns only results existing in table 2

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, sql-view, cross-join

I would like to improve an existing (php/mysql) codebase that presents an overview of choir attendances (X axis: dates, Y axis: students).
The data is spread across various tables (and a very perfectible naming logic, as you will see). The query is quite heavy and to be repeated for each "chorist" so I am trying to construct a VIEW to optimize the backend code.

The involved tables:

- chorale_dates = the rehearsal dates for the season
- chorale_inscriptions = the chorists' registrations
- chorale_presences = the recorded absences (chorists attendances)
- chorale_id = the chorists' personal details (email, name, ...)

```
┌───────────────────────┐      ┌──────────────────────────────────┐  ┌───────────────────────┐
│ chorale_dates         │      │chorale_presences                 │  │ chorale_inscription   │
├───────────────────────┤      ├──────────────────────────────────┤  ├───────────────────────┤
│                       │      │                                  │  │                       │
│ chorale_date_id       │      │chorale_presences_id            ┌─┼──┤►chorale_inscription_id│
│              ▲        │      │                                │ │  │                       │
│              │        │      │                                │ │  │                       │
│              │        │      │                                │ │  │                       │
│              └────────┼──────┤chorale_presences_date_id       │ │  │ chorale_id_id         │
│                       │      │                                │ │  │ │                     │
│                       │      │chorale_presences_inscription_id│ │  │ │                     │
│                       │      │                                  │  │ │                     │
│                       │      │                                  │  │ │                     │
└───────────────────────┘      └──────────────────────────────────┘  └─┼─────────────────────┘
                                                                       │
                                                                       │            ┌───────────────────────┐
                                                                       │            │ chorale_id            │
                                                                       │            ├───────────────────────┤
                                                                       │            │                       │
                                                                       └────────────► chorale_id_id         │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    │                       │
                                                                                    └───────────────────────┘
```

Here is the statement generating the view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `attendances` AS SELECT
    `d`.`chorale_date_id` AS `date_id`,
    `d`.`chorale_date` AS `date`,
    `d`.`chorale_date_saison` AS `season_id`,
    `d`.`chorale_date_type` AS `date_type`,
    `d`.`chorale_date_chorale_id` AS `chorale_id`,
    `d`.`chorale_date_etat` AS `date_etat`,
    `p`.`chorale_presences_id` AS `absence_id`,
    `p`.`chorale_presences_date_id` AS `chorale_presences_date_id`,
    `p`.`chorale_presences_inscription_id` AS `chorale_presences_inscription_id`,
    `i`.`chorale_inscription_id` AS `chorale_inscription_id`,
    `p`.`chorale_presences_etat` AS `attendance`,
    `i`.`chorale_inscription_pupitre` AS `chorale_inscription_pupitre`,
    `p`.`chorale_presences_validation` AS `chorale_presences_validation`,
    CONCAT( `c`.`chorale_id_nom`, ', ', `c`.`chorale_id_prenom`) AS `fullname`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `chorale_dates` `d`
            LEFT JOIN `chorales_presences` `p` ON
                (
                    (
                        `p`.`chorale_presences_date_id` = `d`.`chorale_date_id`
                    )
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `chorale_inscription` `i` ON
            (
                (
                    `p`.`chorale_presences_inscription_id` = `i`.`chorale_inscription_id`
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN `chorale_id` `c` ON
        (
            (
                `c`.`chorale_id_id` = `i`.`chorale_id_id`
            )
        )
    )
ORDER BY d.season_id ASC, `d`.`chorale_date` ASC ;
```

Because it is a LEFT JOIN, I am expecting to have all season dates for all registered chorists, and either an empty "attendance" value if there is no recorded absence in the chorale_presence table, or the column value if there is a matching record in that table. All chorists should have 37 entries, whether there is an entry in chorale_presence or not.

Yet, what this view returns only contains rows having date and an absence recorded. So depending on the chorist, I get varying amount of entries.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The parentheses combine the secondary tables together _before_ combining with `chorale_date`.  I suspect that is not what you intended.  Also, it is probably unwise to 'normalize' dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting to have all season dates for all registered chorists

This is the definition of a `CROSS` join between `chorale_dates` where you store the dates and `chorale_inscriptio` where you store the chorists' registrations:

```
CREATE VIEW attendances AS 
SELECT
  d.chorale_date_id AS date_id,
  d.chorale_date AS date,
  d.chorale_date_saison AS season_id,
  d.chorale_date_type AS date_type,
  d.chorale_date_chorale_id AS chorale_id,
  d.chorale_date_etat AS date_etat,
  p.chorale_presences_id AS absence_id,
  p.chorale_presences_date_id AS chorale_presences_date_id,
  p.chorale_presences_inscription_id AS chorale_presences_inscription_id,
  i.chorale_inscription_id AS chorale_inscription_id,
  p.chorale_presences_etat AS attendance,
  i.chorale_inscription_pupitre AS chorale_inscription_pupitre,
  p.chorale_presences_validation AS chorale_presences_validation,
  CONCAT(c.chorale_id_nom, ', ', c.chorale_id_prenom) AS fullname
FROM chorale_dates d CROSS JOIN chorale_inscription i
LEFT JOIN chorales_presences p ON p.chorale_presences_date_id = d.chorale_date_id AND p.chorale_presences_inscription_id = i.chorale_inscription_id
LEFT JOIN chorale_id c ON c.chorale_id_id = i.chorale_id_id
ORDER BY d.season_id ASC, d.chorale_date ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware of the possibility to do cross join. This is not returning exactly what I need (it returns too many rows) : I will try a cross join using chorale_dates and chorale_inscriptions instead.

Comment: @pixeline if by *...for all registered chorists* you mean that there are chorists who did not register then the CROSS join should be to `chorale_inscriptions`. I will edit.

Comment: thank you for updating your answer. It is getting closer but there are false "absences" appearing. I notice I get NULL for chorale_presences_inscription_id when i have a value for chorale_inscription_id. When there is indeed a record in chorale_absences, there it is correct (both values are the same). I'll update the question with a (summarized) db scheme.

Comment: @pixeline I base all the ON clauses in my code on the relations that I see in your code. The condition is `p.chorale_presences_date_id = d.chorale_date_id AND p.chorale_presences_inscription_id = i.chorale_inscription_id`, so if both the date and the inscription_id don't match you will get null for that date.

Comment: i have updated my question with the db schema, just to be sure. Your query seems correct to me, I don't understand why i get these "almost correct" results. I'll investigate further, but your answer is the right one. I have yet to see if it improves performance though, as the view is quite huge now. Thank you!

Comment: Just to finish the story: I tweaked your query a bit more and it finally worked when i used the "date" column to order the result set. (i used the date_id previously, as the "date" field type is "varchar" I did not trust it for the sorting but it turns out i was wrong. No idea why the developer chose that instead of timestamp... Unfortunately, the optimization i was seeking is not there: it costs almost one second more to perform the entire queries. Probably the huge size of the view is causing the bump.